# How to create a static page on Ghost Blog?

Tags: ghost-blog

I created a page file named "page-timemachine.hbs" on my custom theme's root directory followed a tutorial, and I have added a item on my blog "/ghost/settings/navigation/",like this
[add new navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kC3L4.png)
But when I  visit the link, I got a "404".Did I made anything wrong? thx

Answer (score 1):

You also need to add the page in the admin GUI. You do that by doing the following *(assuming you are on a fairly recent version of Ghost)*:

1. Add a new post
2. Click on Post Settings [image] on the top right of the interface.
3. Click the checkbox **Turn this post into a static page**

After that is done you can simply edit the post as usual and after you've published it, it should appear instead of your 404-error.